# An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor when creating new Ionic project

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I was working with Ionic Framework using AngularJs. Every Thing was fine.
However now, When I am trying to create now Ionic/Angular js Project, I am facing a problem with the capacitor, as following:

[image]

[image]

How to solve this problem?
I could not found a solution from any of the previous posts.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Capacitor 3 was released 2 days ago, and your ionic cli version is not compatible with it, you need to update the ionic cli version

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

the first one is only needed if you were using the old ionic CLI, it was renamed to `@ionic/cli` long ago, but some people is still using it because they didn't know, so I put it here just in case

Comment: Still, when I am trying to build the app, I am getting the same error:  [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
capacitor.cmd run android --no-sync --target Pixel_3_API_29 exited with exit code 1.

Comment: answer was the key. looks that the new version of the capacitor has a lot of changes. Even I re-installed android studio to solve the problems that emerged after the updation.

Comment: It definitely was a hoop to jump through, then afterwards it complained about deleting the capacitor.config.ts. That was it, from there adding Android was not a problem.

Comment: This worked liked a charm, in addition I added `ionic integrations enable capacitor` at the end - thanks

Comment: This solution works with Ionic v7, thanks
Additionally remember to build the project before(ng build) to generate the www directory.