# Ionic 6: unknown option '--npm-client'

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, capacitor

I have a project with ionic 6 and capacitor, when I run `ionic serve` it work like a charm and I can see the project in my browser, but then when I run `ionic capacitor build android` I got this error:

```
error: unknown option '--npm-client'
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
```

I have tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633486/an-error-occurred-while-running-subprocess-capacitor-when-creating-new-ionic-pro), but it didn't work.

It says to:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

but I still get the same error. Someone already got the same error before?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `ionic -v`?

Comment: It is: ionic -v 6.12.2

Comment: Update to the latest version and try again: `npm install -g @ionic/cli@6.19.0`

Comment: Just tryed, but the system still say I'm using the 6.12.2 version. Even when I use the sudo command

Comment: I'm using ubuntu

Comment: You may have installed another local version. Run the following 
`npm uninstall ionic`, `npm uninstall @ionic/cli`, `npm install -g @ionic/cli@6.19.0` and try again.

Comment: Yeah, I did it twice, and the system was not able to remove or change the Ionic version. I have tried to do it with and without sudo command, many times. When I run the uninstall command and than ask for the version it still say that the older version is there, and when I run the install command and than ask for the version, it still say that I keep the older version

Answer (score 10):

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm install -g @ionic/cli@latest
```

Try this

Comment: Same error still.

Answer (score 1):

I fix it updating to the last version with this, because the upgrade commands didn't work for me.

```
cd /tmp
wget https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic/cli/-/cli-6.19.0.tgz
sudo npm -g install cli-6.19.0.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had to upgrade from node 14 to node 16.15 to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling cli and installing latest cli did not work for me.
The following steps worked:

```
1. ionic build
2. npm install @capacitor/android
3. npx cap init
4. npx cap add android
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue is caused by older version of ionic-cli, you should upgrade the CLI version.

Comment: doesnt work. still says unknown option